# how to install portaudio on pi properly

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, pyaudio, portaudio

I am working on a project that involves recording from a mic on a raspberry pi.
for now i am getting this error while the program is running.

> python3: src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:3641:
>   PaAlsaStreamComponent_BeginPolling: Assertion `ret == self->nfds'
>   failed. Aborted

while searching for ways to fix this, i figured out the file pa_linux_alsa.c belongs to port audio. please refer to the following links.

[modified pa_linux_alsa.c i think](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/tickets/268/details)

[how to install port audio](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/portaudio/Platforms_RaspberryPi)

[download link](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html)

first link is about the error and a modified fix, still dont know where to copy and the last two are about installing portaudio. apparently there is no easier way to install this with a command.

i downloaded the pa_snapshot enhanced  version of it. *but i dont know where i am supposed to put these files* to begin to configure and make as in the readme. I copied the portaudio directory in to **home/pi** (in the user i think. "**cd**" and copied it there) then did as in the readme and rebooted the system. i dont see any changes in the error in program. i tried using the command **whereis** with pa_**linux_alsa.c**. that command also doesn't show the file or anything related to portaudio.

Comment: To anyone coming here, this issue is not exclusive to Raspberri Pi

Answer (score 10):

Your first link correctly identifies a bug in portaudio, but the fix is incomplete. I forked the portaudio library and created a patch to fix this. Here are the steps to remove the portaudio package and compile the patched version from source:

```
sudo apt-get remove libportaudio2
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
git clone -b alsapatch https://github.com/gglockner/portaudio
cd portaudio
./configure && make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ..
```

At this point, you should have a patched portaudio library, based on the pa_stable_v190600_20161030 tag. Finally, if you need the PyAudio package for Python, then install it using pip: `sudo pip3 install pyaudio`.

Comment: commit 80aafc6 (i.e. tip of your `alsapatch` branch) seems to unnecessarily remove a lot of error handling.  I submitted a tidier version of the [patch to the portaudio mailing list](https://lists.columbia.edu/pipermail/portaudio/2019-July/001888.html) which might be preferable

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fully addressed/solved upstream already?

Comment: I've just noticed that [Debian is pulling in my patch](https://sources.debian.org/patches/portaudio19/19.6.0-1.1/944509-crash.patch/) now.  Hence using package version 19.6.0-1.1 (or later) would presumably fix it on Debian.  Ubuntu doesn't seem to have picked it up yet, and I can't test because I'm using Arch these days

Comment: [Looks like](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/portaudio19/19.6.0-1.1/+publishinghistory) it made it into the next Ubuntu release, [if I'm looking properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277958/package-integration-process-from-debian-case-in-point-portaudio).

Comment: From what I can see a fix for this (switching the assertion to at least better error handling) was merged with this pull request https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/pull/344 on 18. December 2020

Comment: This post needs more up-votes. The first post I've seen for this specific issue that actually works.